# Can you append console output to file in pycharm?

Tags: logging, pycharm

Pycharm has an option to save console output to a file, however, it will wipe the previous file when you restart the program.  Is there anyway to get this to append instead?  If not, can you dynamically change the filename it saves to on each run? Like add a timestamp so each run would save to a new file?